# Python and MongoEngine, TypeError: Object of type ValidationError is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, api, tornado, mongoengine

What I'm trying to is building a REST API using python tornado, all were work well until I got this message when I post data to the API "TypeError: Object of type ValidationError is not JSON serializable".

```
def post(self):
    try:
        data = convert_arguments(self.request.arguments)
        self.write(dict(result=HazardManager().create_hazard(**data)))
    except Exception as e:
        self.write(dict(error=e))
```

`create_hazard()` is the function that makes the connect with the database and it says to save my data and return the object

```
def create_hazard(self, **data):
    try:
        hazard = HazardDB(title=data['title'], datetime=data['datetime'], location=data['location'], description=data['description'])
        hazard.commit(True) 
        return hazard.to_json()
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

Here how I call the POST method in my client side,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'api/v1/hazards',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `self.write` [tries to convert your dictionary to JSON](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.write). But it fails because it can't convert ValidationError object to the JSON representation (most if not all exceptions objects couldn't be converted to JSON if it's haven't been added by a developer). Easy way to avoid that is to pass an exception message, not an exception object:

```
...
except Exception as e:
    self.write(dict(error=str(e)))
```